# Create a MS SQL View linking to a table in different host database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two databases. lets name them A and B. The database B is in different IP with different username and password. But I want to create a view in Database A linking to a table in Database B. How can I achieve this because of database B authentication.

Comment: You can create linked server from A to B and specify credentials which should be used during connection to that database B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a linked Server in your Server in which DatabaseA exists.

You can google how to create Linked Server in SQL Server

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server='ServerNameOfDatabaseB', 
   @srvproduct='',
   @provider='SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc='NCSUSPRODSQL02'
```

Once you create linked server then your view code would be something like the below.

```
CREATE VIEW Viewname
AS
SELECT *
FROM LinkedServerName.DatabaseB.SchemaName.TableName
```

Comment: I tried. For example if I have the connection string to database B like `Data Source=XX.XX.XX.XX;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;User ID=user;Password=password;Max Pool Size=1000; Pooling=True;Connection Timeout=0; MultipleActiveResultSets=True`. Then how I would i specify user authentication details in EXEC statement.

Comment: This is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188279.aspx) to the MS docs on linked servers.  And [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx) is another to an MS tutorial.

Comment: Darshaka: You already specified your authentication details in DataSource. You are passing DataSource to Exec statement. So no need to pass authentication details again to Exec separately.